# Which type of page to use?

Tags: oracle-apex

I would like to build a page, which is bound to single table and has 2 essential columns: file data as blob and file name as varchar.

[image]

So each row in the page represents a row in table. User should be able to upload data(without refreshing the page), remove or download existing one.

Question is which type of page will allow me building such page, by adding file browse/upload buttons for each row?

APEX 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some options you could consider, though based on your comments to @Littlefoot's answer you may not find them suitable.

1) You could create the Browse, Upload, Remove and Download actions as columns of type Link in a Classic Report, Interactive Report or Interactive Grid. The links could open a modal form if needed e.g. for Browse, or you could use a dynamic action to make them do something bespoke e.g. run some Javascript. You could use CSS to make the links look more like buttons.

2) You could define the Browse etc. actions using bespoke HTML in the SQL query, setting the column type to Display Only, with "Escape special characters" set to No.  Again this can be done with any of the 3 report types.  For example:

```
select filename
     , '<button type="button" id="browse-' || file_id || '">Browse</button>' browse
       ...
```

Now you can use dynamic actions to make the buttons do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you'd like to do, that would be a tabular form page (which is now placed under the *Legacy pages* in the *Create page* wizard), as it allows you to *add* a new row as many times as you want.

Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, you can't use a *file browse* item in it. There are *Display image* or *Download BLOB* item types, but none of them allows you to upload an image.

Another page type (available since, huh, 5.1, I think), which kind of *replaces* tabular pages, is an interactive grid. Though, the same goes for it - there's no way to add anything related to BLOB upload to it.

A couple of years ago, when I had to develop a page similar to yours (using Apex 4.x), I created a HTML page and manually added 10 "file browse" items whose storage type was the WWV_FLOW_FILES table (which is now deprecated; you'd use APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES instead).

It worked fine, but allowed only 10 files to be uploaded in parallel. That certainly isn't as good as we'd want it to be, but it was good enough for our needs.

I did some research (right now), found several OTN Forums discussions about the same subject, but none of the authors made it work.

Maybe you could do what you want with some other techniques (such as JavaScript), but I really wouldn't know how to do that. Sorry for not being able to help you any better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think HTML file browse buttons would work for me, because they should be dynamically bound to the rows.

Comment: Right; so, I understood what you need, but can't help.

Comment: If nothing else helps, you can still use *form with report* which creates an interactive report (so that you could review what you've got) and a form - for a single item - that enables you to upload image.

Comment: Form for single item will make the whole thing useless. It's necessary to have all in one page. I'm looking towards dynamic actions and if possible to have custom columns in report, where I can place html browse button and bind to dynamic action? I even can generate the whole HTML code dynamically if there is a way to use HTML template with placeholders for the rows.

Comment: I don't know, that's beyond my knowledge.